# Unique paths from (0,0) to (N-1, N-1) in a 2D grid with a twist

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming

A path can only go left and bottom in the grid starting at (0,0). Eventually it needs to get to (N-1, N-1).

If the grid is NxN, there are 2N choose N such paths, which exponentially increase with increase in N, and I can't store all those paths in list because of memory constraints. We can also encode each path into bit strings of length 2^(N-1), where 1 is right movement and 0 is down movement. There are equal number of 0s and 1s in each encoded path.

I have been given a 2D square grid of dimension NxN. Each cell in the grid has a non-negative value. I need to sum all those values for each unique path. How can I do this effectively?

Comment: By summing the values in the cells along the path?

Comment: Imagine you have a 30x30 grid, how would you effectively enumerate the sum of values along each unique path?

Comment: construct all unique paths using a breadth first search of the problem space. Sum the values of the nodes along the paths.

Comment: Since this is a dynamic programming problem, think about the simpler case where the matrix is just an array, or a 1xN grid. In this case the sums you are looking for, i.e., from 0 to the i-th element in the array, is simply the cumulative sum for position i. It's easy to extend this approach to the matrix case. So you only need another matrix to represent the cumulative sums and it should take linear time to compute them.

Comment: @MattCoubrough, Any hint on how I can construct a BFS tree for this? Given that I have the tree I would be able to do preorder traversal on it.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta, I don't think your technique will work. Think about it, there are 2N choose N such paths, how can it take linear time?

Comment: Due to your constraint that you can only travel left and down and you can encode the different paths in bit strings, and then simply linearly traverse every possible bitstring. Every valid path will have the same number of lefts and downs in total.

Comment: @MattCoubrough, the problem is I don't know how I can construct those bit strings... I am new to algorithm problems.

Comment: I think you are overestimating the number of possible paths in the matrix. At each step you can choose only two possible directions, unless you already hit one of the two edges of the grid, in which case your choice is only one. I haven't done the math but this sounds to me like it greatly simplifies the problem and that's also where the suboptimality is.

Answer (score 2):

Let's call the value matrix V, so V[y][x] is the value at the cell (x, y).

Every path starts at (0, 0) and ends at (N - 1, N - 1). The total value of a path P, value(P) is the sum of the values of all the cells lying on P.

The problem is to calculate SUM(value(P)) for all valid paths P from (0, 0) to (N - 1, N -1).

Instead of enumerating each valid path, an alternate way to compute SUM is to compute for each cell (x, y), how many paths go through this cell. If there are i paths going through this cell, then the total value contributed by this cell is i * V[y][x]. So, we simply loop through each cell in the grid, compute i(x, y) for it, add i(x, y) * V[y][x] to the total result.

How to compute i(x, y)? i(x, y) is simply the no. of valid paths going from (0, 0) to (N-1, N-1) via (x, y). Hint :- If there are a ways to reach (x, y) from (0, 0) and b ways to reach (N-1, N-1) from (x, y), then there are a * b ways to reach from (0, 0) to (N-1, N-1) via (x, y). Rest is easy enough.

Comment: From what I understood, this will output the sum of all paths, is there a way to get the sum of each path separately? Thanks!